# Setting a password to microsoft documents recursively

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, password-protection

Trying to set this code found [Here](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/quickly-protect-batch-word-documents-password/) to work recursively down through my folders. at the minute I have this

```
 Public Sub addPassword()
 
  Dim FSO As Object
  Dim strFileName As String
  Dim strFilePath As String
  Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object
  Dim doc As Object
  Dim oDoc As Document
  Dim PWD As String
  
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  folderPath = "G:\Test Data"
  Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)
  
  PWD = "FooBar"
  For Each doc In folder.Files
        strFilePath = "G:\Test Data\"
        strFileName = Dir$(strFilePath & "*.doc*")
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open( _
                   FileName:=strFilePath & strFileName, _
                   PasswordDocument:="FooBar")
        oDoc.Saved = False
        oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strFilePath & strFileName, _
            Password:=PWD
        oDoc.Close
        Set oDoc = Nothing
        
  Next
  For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
  For Each doc In subfolder.Files
        strFilePath = "G:\Test Data\"
        strFileName = Dir$(strFilePath & "*.doc*")
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open( _
                   FileName:=strFilePath & strFileName, _
                   PasswordDocument:="FooBar")
        oDoc.Saved = False
        oDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=strFilePath & strFileName, _
            Password:=PWD
      
        oDoc.Close
        Set oDoc = Nothing
        
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Absolute Novice to vba so trying to use some limited python experience to set this up recursively. I can see every file open up in the side but when I go to check on them non of them have a password set

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: There is something wrong with the loop. `For Each doc In folder.Files` but `doc` is never used. Additionally, why bother with `Dir` when you are already using `FSO`? You have full access to the folder contents with `FSO` there is no need for `Dir` anymore.

Comment: Take the file search part out of your main code and move it to a separate method - eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773155/how-to-make-this-code-apply-recursively-to-all-sub-folders/70774654#70774654

Comment: To fix the loop, remove `strFilePath = "G:\Test Data\"` and `strFileName = Dir$(strFilePath & "*.doc*")` and add `If doc.Type = "Microsoft Office Word Document" Then` and change  `Documents.Open(FileName:=doc.Path`

Comment: @Toddleson Brilliant would you happen to know why I'm getting a compile error on the doc.path line have it as  `Documents.Open(FileName:=doc.Path)` Getting expected =

Comment: @TylerKarch Add the code to this post, or make a new post with all of the details of the new problem you are encountering. I'm sure you can get an answer quickly.